# How do I place a directory on my network on the local view of filezilla in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, networking, filezilla

I am trying to get to a folder on my local network on the local view of filezilla in Mac OS X.  When I browse to network I can see the folder fine.  But I can't browse to it in filezilla ( Network inside \ is empty).  When I try these paths it says 'path not found':

```
smb:\\myNAS\
\\myNAS\
\Network\myNAS\
```

I'm not really a Mac guy but I'm totally confused why I can't seem to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Using the Finder menu bar, click Go -> Connect to Server.
2. Type in smb://myNAS/
3. Choose the share that you want to *mount* (let's called it SharedFolder). The mounted share is now located in /Volumes/SharedFolder.
4. In FileZilla or any other application, you can now access /Volumes/SharedFolder as though it was local.

It's like Map Network Drive in Windows, assuming you're a Windows guy. Hope this helps!